# Read value of address

Tags: c#

I want to read the value of an address than I found with Cheat Engine from a game, how can I read the value of that address? I have this code but it returns the bytes read, how can I make to return the value?

```
 const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;
        const int addr = 0x10ACE333;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
        int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Process")[0];
            IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4]; //To read a 4 byte unicode string

            ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, addr, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer) +
                  " (" + bytesRead.ToString() + "bytes)");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What is in `buffer`?

Comment: I'm new in c#, code that is attached i copied from another question... I want to read the value of a memory address like in CE i can see it's value, I want to see it in C#

Comment: For that, you need to know what is the actual internal type. Some "values" may be on one byte (0 to 255, or -128 to 127), other on two bytes (0 to 32767, or ~-16k to ~16k) etc... Do you have any clue what it could be? First, knowing the number of bytes used would be the most important step. Usual "integer" values are on 4 bytes, usual "floating point" values are on 4 bytes/32bits for single precision, or 8 bytes/64bit for double precision etc..

Comment: I see on CE Type is 4 Bytes, now that I know the internal type, what should I do to read it's value?

Comment: First, get the 4 bytes as an array of bytes. Then, you can use `BitConverter` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int . `int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);` If that doesn't work, you might try to reverse the array of bytes prior to conversion. (actuall, you don't need to create another array, the second parameter is the starting index for your value). In my example, I assume you have a stadnard integer similar to .NET `Int32` value.

Comment: After reading in details your code, maybe my answr is completely off : you are examining _unicode characters_, right?

Comment: Yes I'm trying that, not sure why as I said I'm quite new and the code I've copied from another post, I'm just trying to get the value from an address, like on CE does it, but in C#(maybe with C++ it would be easier?)

Comment: Ok, start to read the correct number of bytes, in the example you are reading 20 bytes. Then remove comments that are not relevant (and probably wrong), because it confuses readers :=) . And if you know the value is an integer (and not a decimal value), then try the `BitConvert` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215227/discussion-between-rsm-and-pac0).

Comment: @RSM : sorry, I can't connect to the chat for some networking reason currently

Answer (score 1):

This is how you read a null terminated wide char array in C#:

```
public static string ReadNullTerminatedWString(IntPtr handle, IntPtr addr, int maxlength)
{
    var bytearray = new byte[maxlength * 2];

    IntPtr bytesread = IntPtr.Zero;

    ReadProcessMemory(handle, addr, bytearray, maxlength * 2, out bytesread);

    int nullterm = 0;
    while (nullterm < bytesread.ToInt64() && bytearray[nullterm] != 0)
    {
        nullterm = nullterm + 2;
    }

    string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytearray, 0, nullterm);

    return s;
}
```